# How to disable "Validating Web Site" step when building an ASP.NET Web Site project?

Tags: visual-studio, build-process, asp.net

Sometimes, I want to skip validation of the web site to save time when I build an ASP.NET Web Site project. Is there a Visual Studio option or any other means to turn off this behaviour?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Re: How do I turn off 'validating web
>   pages'. May 21, 2008 02:52 AM
>
> Hi,
>
> Validating Web Site is important. It
>   does the following tasks:
>
> Validate web.config to make sure that
>   all settings are legal. Validate aspx
>   page's markup. List error in the Error
>   List.  **If you don't want to validate,
>   you can set your project to "No Build"
>   or "Build Page" before running startup
>   page.**
>
> For more information, please refer to
>   http://forums.asp.net/t/939998.aspx.
>
> I hope this helps.
>
> Thomas Sun  Microsoft Online Community
>   Support

-- http://forums.asp.net/t/1262277.aspx

Website project, Property Pages (in VS 2010):

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work in some cases.  I have a web service site as part of my solution and every time I build anything that depends on it, it does the "validating web site" step even though I have it set to No Build.

Comment: This answer seems to not apply to the validation of websites before I am running a unit test in another project.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the earlier service packs had issues with Validating taking a while (days in some cases). Check and see if you can update Visual Studio and seem if that resolves the issue.

Comment: If you get an error like you've described you should debug the issue http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikhailarkhipov/archive/2007/09/19/how-to-obtain-debug-information-from-a-hung-frozen-application.aspx last time it happened to me it was due to a corrupt file.